# SQL query to get matching records with the given collection elements(all elements should match) need with AND not OR

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I have a below query:

```
select count(*) 
from propertyattributelink as p 
where p.attributeId IN (40,41,45,52);
```

It returns all the records which have *any* of the listed attributeId's (either 40 or 41 or 45 or 52).

I need only the records which have *all* the attributes(40 AND 41 AND 45 AND 52)

Note: the list size is not fixed. Here the size is 4, it may be 10 or 15, it can have dynamic values based on user selection.

Can anyone suggest how to get the correct result?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use aggregation here to check for the present of all the attributes.  In the query below I assume that `id` is column in the `propertyattributelink` table over which you want to group.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM propertyattributelink t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM propertyattributelink
    WHERE attributeId IN (40, 41, 45, 52)
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attributeId) = 4
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```